# retrieve label text from tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

i have just begun experimenting on using table layout panel to keep things organised. I have added a label control with some text into a cell. how do I get this text back into a string variable at a later time? or even modify the text in the label in the cell?

Comment: what is the problem exactly? did you forget if the label was called label1 so cannot find it any more or are you adding the label dynamically and you want to know how to keep a reference to it?

Comment: hmmm I have programatically added the label into the cells during form_load. I want to use some other controls to update the text of this label, and also get this text and write it to a text file. how do i get the reference to it in this case if that is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the control, just store a reference to it in the form.

Add this to the main form body (not inside a method):

```
Label myLabel;
```

in your code that adds the label:

```
myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "Some Text";
// Pseudo-code
myPanel.Cells.Add(myLabel);
```

Then later, just access myLabel anywhere in the form code.